# What JVM are you using with ColdFusion 8.01 and Windows 2003?

Tags: coldfusion, java

I have CF 8.01 on Windows 2003 (both 64 bit and 32 bit versions). I need to do some performance tuning on the JVM but wanted to start with what the community thought was the best JVM. In a production environment which JVM version are you all having the best performance and stability with?

Answer (score 2):

I am currently running 1.6.0_11 with my CF 8.0.1 servers, and 1.4.2_17 with my CF 7.0.2 production servers (32-bit).  We've found these to be very stable when the JVM settings are tuned properly.

There are newer versions of the 1.6 line, but I have not tested them in production environments yet.

[Java SE 6 HotSpot VM GC Tuning](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/gc_tuning_6.html)

Answer (score 2):

On ColdFusion 8 installations that use the default JVM and make use of CFC-based frameworks, application initialization will experience a noticeable lag in startup of several minutes (do not confuse app start up with server startup).

See http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5218663.

This issue has been fixed in Sun JVM 1.6.0_11.   Using this JVM version or higher on ColdFusion 8 will resolve the slow application initialization for CFC-based apps.  The JVM setting can be changed in the ColdFusion8\runtime\bin\jvm.config file.

Answer (score 0):

We just deployed 1.6.0_16 on our dev box this weekend. So far it seems to be quite stable and quick. Note the previously mentioned issues prior to 1.6.0_11.

We would love to see what you come back with as your tweaked JVM config options!